# Gracefully close *persistent* connections on shutdown

Tags: rust, actix-web

When an `actix-web`-based application receives a `SIGTERM` signal, it will gracefully shut down by:

- not accepting any new connections
- still finishing serving ongoing requests (up to a configurable time limit)

and will then shut down once all client connections have been closed.

However, it seems the application will make no attempt at closing existing **connections** that are kept alive by the client, neither as part of a response to the client nor proactively on idle connections. This means that persistent connections are not closed gracefully, but rather are dropped once the timeout is reached - which in turn will let the next client request on the connection fail.

Is there some way to configure `actix-web`-based applications for a more graceful way of closing persistent connections?

Comment: Actix-web does not provide a built-in mechanism. You would need to implement own solution, something like: keep track of all active connections. Then intercept `sigterm` with a handler, that will close all active connections.

Comment: @99problems Does actix-web even provide access to the set of active connections so that I could keep track of them?